# adding a mass action to Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, routes, crm

I am trying to add a mass action for selecting leads and then updating the sales person. I added this route:

```
Route::post('mass-update-salesperson', 'LeadController@massUpdateSalesperson')->name('admin.leads.mass_update_salesperson');
```

and in the LeadController I added this method:

```
public function massUpdateSalesperson()
{
    $data = request()->all();

    foreach ($data['rows'] as $leadId) {
        $lead = $this->leadRepository->find($leadId);

        $lead->update(['user_id' => $data['value']]);

        Event::dispatch('lead.update.before', $leadId);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'message' => trans('admin::app.response.update-success', ['name' => trans('admin::app.leads.title')])
    ]);
}
```

and in the LeadDataGrid I added this code :

```
public function prepareMassActions()
{
    $stages = [];

    foreach ($this->pipeline->stages->toArray() as $stage) {
        $stages[$stage['name']] = $stage['id'];
    }

    $this->addMassAction([
        'type'   => 'delete',
        'label'  => trans('ui::app.datagrid.delete'),
        'action' => route('admin.leads.mass_delete'),
        'method' => 'PUT',
    ]);

    $this->addMassAction([
        'type'    => 'update',
        'label'   => trans('admin::app.datagrid.update_stage'),
        'action'  => route('admin.leads.mass_update'),
        'method'  => 'PUT',
        'options' => $stages,
    ]);

       //newly added
     $this->addMassAction([
        'type'    => 'update',
        'label'   => trans('admin::app.datagrid.update_salesperson'),
        'action'  => route('admin.leads.mass_update_salesperson'),
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'options' => $this->getUserDropdownOptions(),
     ]);
}
```

it reads the function but it won't update, any ideas why?

it gives an error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
> update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`crm-database`.`leads`, CONSTRAINT `leads_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN
> KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL:
> update `leads` set `user_id` = {"value":7,"label":"sales person
> name","disabled":false,"selected":false,"image_url":null},
> `leads`.`updated_at` = 2023-06-16 18:39:11 where `id` = 2492)

noting that this user exists in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you pls dump and share the value of that `$data` variable. It is failing because you are assigning `user_id`, which is supposed to be an integer, with this value:

```json
{"value":7,"label":"sales person name","disabled":false,"selected":false,"image_url":null}
```

My guess is, you got to do this:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$lead->update(['user_id' => $data['value']['value']]);

// Or
$lead->update(['user_id' => Arr::get($data, 'value.value')]);
```

Comment: Thank you, that actually worked, but how do I get it to display the username instead of user ID in the drop down menu. I will show you the code I tried.

Comment: Here's the LeadController modified code:
```
public function massUpdateSalesperson()
    {
        $data = request()->all();
    
        foreach ($data['rows'] as $leadId) {
            $lead = $this->leadRepository->find($leadId);
    
    $lead->update(['user_id' => Arr::get($data, 'value.value')]);
    
    Event::dispatch('lead.update.before', $leadId);
        }
    
        return response()->json([
            'message' => trans('admin::app.response.update-success', ['name' => trans('admin::app.leads.title')])
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: DataGrid Modified code:

public function prepareMassActions()   {
       
 $users = User::all();
    $UserName = [];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $UserName[$user['name']] = $user['id'];
    }
         $this->addMassAction([
            'type'    => 'update',
            'label'   => trans('admin::app.datagrid.update_salesperson'),
            'action'  => route('admin.leads.mass_update_salesperson'),
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'options' => $UserName,
]);
    }
}

Comment: Pls put that in a new question with clarity.

Comment: I would really appreciate your help here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76499913/change-laravel-mass-action-drop-down-menu-items-from-value-to-name